# How to understand CSS3 3D Transform Perspective

Tags: css, html

I am testing CSS3 3D Transform in Safari, but I found that the 3D model is far from my knowledge. 
After consulting the Holy W3C Document, i discovered all transform rules in CSS3 will be translated to transform matrix which is similar to the one used in SVG standards : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TranslationDefined
OMG, I am not good at math.
Is there anybody who can explain to me how to understand the behavior of transform functions such as rotateX, perspective, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've generally found I have not needed the actual transformation matrix for anything I've done. Use the individual properties instead. I use http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html as documentation.

Comment: thx~it seems its 3d model is fairly simple if you read some books about computer graphics......

Answer (score 3):

I have written some tuts and demos on CSS 3D transforms including CSS3 3D matrix-transforms: http://www.eleqtriq.com

Comment: great tut! I figured out how to play with CSS3 3D anyway, but still thx!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten round to looking at it properly, but I'm no good at maths either. Try this though, might help understand how properties work the http://westciv.com/tools/3Dtransforms/